# Help with jQuery Roundabout Library

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm about to start working on building a website. The design is in the format of content sitting behind and you click it brings it to the front. In a stack order. The design is [Here](http://apili.net/jquery/design.jpg)

The basic concept is to follow the jQuery Roundabout idea. Buuuuuuuuut the problem I have is when HTML is added into each box, when it moves to the back it doesn't scale correctly. It keeps the same size. Ideally I'd like it to scale to match, but not having much look.

Any ideas on how I can manage this? My example is [Here](http://apili.net/jquery/)

Code is also here :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Roundabout</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js" /></script>
<script src="js/jquery.roundabout.min.js" /></script>
<script src="js/jquery.roundabout-shapes.min.js" /></script>

<style>
    body { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; }
    p { font-size: 11px; }
   .roundabout-holder { padding: 0; height: 5em; }
   .roundabout-moveable-item {
      height: 4em;
      width: 4em;
      cursor: pointer;
   }
   .roundabout-moveable-item h1 {
       font-size: 11px;
   }
   .body { width: auto !important; }
   .roundabout-in-focus { cursor: auto; }
</style> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="myRoundabout">
   <div class="box">
        <h1>Contact events4fun</h1>
        <p>HTML Element In Here</p>
        <p>email : test@test.com</p>
    </div>
   <div class="box">Box 2</div>
   <div class="box">Box 3</div>
   <div class="box">Box 4</div>
   <div class="box">Box 5</div>
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myRoundabout').roundabout({
         shape: 'diagonalRingLeft',
         childSelector: 'div.box',
         minScale: 0.1,
         maxScale: 1.2
      });
   });
</script> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you forgot to include the relevant code.

Comment: Fair point, code is also included.. :)

Comment: It looks like you are only changing the font size of the box and not it's contents.

Comment: @fudgey - I've tried to resize the box to suit, But the content within it still doesnt scale.

Comment: Try changing the `childSelector` to `div.box > *`

Comment: Like this: childSelector: 'div.box > *' ? That seems to stop the Roundabout from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the font size is controlled from the wrapper. And in your example, the font size for the `<p>` and `<h1>` are set using `px`, so it doesn't resize.

Try just completely removing these two lines in your css, or switching them to `em` or `%`.

```
p { font-size: 11px; }
.roundabout-moveable-item h1 { font-size: 11px; }
```

Comment: Cracking thanks for that. Just looking at the further CSS its all built in em's. Seems the way to go. Should be fun trying to build large HTML Div's with Form content etc in them.